# T SQL Extract String between penultimate and last comma

Tags: sql-server, string, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I'm using MS SQL Server 2014 SP3.

I have a column called `person_loader` that contains one large string.  I have no control over this as its from a 3rd party system.

Sample data:

```
1. Bob Smith, 01/01/1980, "email: bob@test.com, mobile: 012345687",USA, Joiner, 05/04/2022
2. Dolly Smith, 02/03/1978, "email: dolly@test.com", UK, Singer,
3. Dave Smith, 09/08/78,"mobile: 98745632", USA, Unemployed, 04/04/2022
4. Bud Smith, 07/07/80,"email:bud.smith@test.com, mobile: 0147852369", UK, Dr,
```

I want to extract the string between the penultimate and last ','. Here is the result:

```
1. Joiner
2. Singer
3. Unemployed
4. Dr
```

Sometimes the string won't end with the date, but there will always be a comma.

I can extract everything right of the last comma, but how do I build on this?

```
SELECT RIGHT([person_loader], CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE([person_loader])) - 1)
FROM tblCustomer;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In newer (and supported) versions of SQL Server, this can be much easier with, say, `OPENJSON`. In older, unsupported versions, you're stuck with ugly string parsing... not one of SQL Server's strong suits.

```
;WITH level1 AS
(
  SELECT pl = SUBSTRING
         (
           person_loader, 
           1, 
           LEN(person_loader) - CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE(person_loader))
         )
    FROM dbo.tblCustomer
)
SELECT LTRIM(RIGHT(pl, CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE(pl))-1)) FROM level1;
```

Output:

| (No column name) |
| --- |
| Joiner |
| Singer |
| Unemployed |
| Dr |

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=beec12bc59df869d11c27dd9f281c909)

This will fail, of course, if there are strings in the table with one or zero commas. You can deal with this (along with empty strings and `NULL`) using a bunch of additional (and even uglier) `COALESCE(NULLIF(` handling:

```
;WITH level1 AS
(
  SELECT pl = SUBSTRING
    (
      person_loader, 
      1, 
      LEN(person_loader) 
        - COALESCE(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', 
          REVERSE(person_loader)),0),0)
    )
    FROM dbo.tblCustomer
)
SELECT COALESCE(LTRIM(RIGHT(pl, 
  COALESCE(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', 
  REVERSE(pl)), 0),1)-1)), '')
FROM level1;
```